# Finding the error in the solution for: In how many strings of length $n$ composed of $\{0,1\}$ there's at least $m$ zeros

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the error in the following solution to the question: In how many strings of length $n$ composed of $\{0,1\}$ there's at least $m$ zeros?
>
> Solution: choose $m$ places for the zeros, in the rest of the places choose either $0$ or $1$ therefore: $\binom n m 2^{n-m}$.

From trying out small numbers I can see that it's wrong but I don't see why it's wrong to choose places for the zeros other than maybe making a distinction of 'first' zeros, dividing by $m!$ to cancel that isn't right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcounting. For example the solution that has $n$ zeros is counted $\binom{n}{m}$ times.

You can try to solve this using inclusion exclusion to get a rather unpleasant sum.

Alternatively count the sequences with exactly $m$ zeros, exactly $m+1$ zeros and so on and then add them, this yields $\sum\limits_{i=m}^n \binom{n}{m}$ which does not have a nice closed form.

Comment: If there's $n$ ones then there are no zeros so $\binom n 0 =1$...

Comment: yeah, I swapped one with zero, fixed.

Comment: It's the same since $\binom n n =1$

Comment: Maybe you meant it's counted $2^n$ times?

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Your solution says choose $m$ places for the zero and choose $0$ or $1$ for the rest. With this idea in mind the solution that consists of $n$ zeroes is being taken into account once every time you choose $\binom{n}{m}$ zeros . SO you are counting it $\binom{n}{m}$ times.

Comment: Doesn't $m$ represent the amount of zeros and $n$ the total length? if so then in a string of only zeros we'll have $m=n$.

Comment: You want to count the number of sequences of length $n$ with at least $m$ zeroes (where $m$ is a fixed integer). You say this is $\binom{n}{m}$ because we first choose $m$ zeroes and then select the remaining positions in $2^{n-m}$ ways. This is wrong because the sequence with $n$ zeros is counted for each of the $\binom{n}{m}$ selections of $m$ zeros.

Comment: I got it, we just look at a string of only zeros which has only one way to form, but with the wrong solution it's over counted. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help!